# how to count object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, i want to count the number of objects in this.

Using eval function i was able to get the elements, but don know how to count the total objects in this. Can anybody please help me??

```
var txt = '{
    "employees": [{
        "a": "wkn",
        "d": "Wipro Technologies \u2013 IT Services, Product Engineering Solutions, Technology Infrastructure Services, Business Process Outsourcing, Consulting Services",
        "n": "",
        "u": "http://wipro.com/",
        "t": ["outsourcing", "offshore", "india"],
        "dt": "2009-06-26T10:26:02Z"
    }, {
        "a": "shaktimaan",
        "d": "Wipro Technologies \u2013 IT Services, Product Engineering Solutions, Technology Infrastructure Services, Business Process Outsourcing, Consulting Services",
        "n": "Wipro Technologies is the No 1 provider of integrated business, technology and process solutions on a global delivery platform.",
        "u": "http://wipro.com/",
        "t": ["Indian", "IT", "Services", "Companies"],
        "dt": "2011-09-16T17:31:25Z"
    }, {
        "a": "tonemcd",
        "d": "Offshore Outsourcing | IT Services",
        "n": "",
        "u": "http://wipro.com/",
        "t": ["outsourcing", "IT"],
        "dt": "2007-11-04T03:53:18Z"
    }]
}'; //added \n for readability

var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");



document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML=obj.employees[1].a 
document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=obj.employees[1].u
```

This is the response i got for this:

```
First Name: shaktimaan
Last Name: http://wipro.com/
```

I was able to fetch the elemtns, but i want object count.

Comment: Don't use eval, use JSON.parse

Answer (score 8):

You can use `length`:

```
obj.employees.length
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wavXY/3/

I recommend using `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`. Please go through this link for more details: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

Being a JS noob, looking at your employees array I myself wondered how it could be traversed. I experimented a little and maybe its not most efficient way but it helped me understand how to traverse and count something like this.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bSMQn/

```
var txt = '{"employees":[{"a": "wkn", "d": "Wipro Technologies \u2013 IT Services, Product Engineering Solutions, Technology Infrastructure Services, Business Process Outsourcing, Consulting Services", "n": "", "u": "http://wipro.com/", "t": ["outsourcing", "offshore", "india"], "dt": "2009-06-26T10:26:02Z"}, {"a": "shaktimaan", "d": "Wipro Technologies \u2013 IT Services, Product Engineering Solutions, Technology Infrastructure Services, Business Process Outsourcing, Consulting Services", "n": "Wipro Technologies is the No 1 provider of integrated business, technology and process solutions on a global delivery platform.", "u": "http://wipro.com/", "t": ["Indian", "IT", "Services", "Companies"], "dt": "2011-09-16T17:31:25Z"}, {"a": "tonemcd", "d": "Offshore Outsourcing | IT Services", "n": "", "u": "http://wipro.com/", "t": ["outsourcing", "IT"], "dt": "2007-11-04T03:53:18Z"}]}';

var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");
var i =0;
for (;i<obj.employees.length;i++)
{
    document.writeln("Employee " + i+":<br/><br/>");
    var j = 0;
    for(v in obj.employees[i])
    {
        j++;
        document.writeln(v + " => " + obj.employees[i][v] +"<br/>");
    }
    document.writeln("<b>Count:" + j +"</b>");
    document.writeln("<hr/><br/>");

}
```

Output

```
Employee 0:

a => wkn
d => Wipro Technologies – IT Services, Product Engineering Solutions, Technology Infrastructure Services, Business Process Outsourcing, Consulting Services
n => 
u => http://wipro.com/
t => outsourcing,offshore,india
dt => 2009-06-26T10:26:02Z
Count:6

Employee 1:

a => shaktimaan
d => Wipro Technologies – IT Services, Product Engineering Solutions, Technology Infrastructure Services, Business Process Outsourcing, Consulting Services
n => Wipro Technologies is the No 1 provider of integrated business, technology and process solutions on a global delivery platform.
u => http://wipro.com/
t => Indian,IT,Services,Companies
dt => 2011-09-16T17:31:25Z
Count:6
```

....etc

Hope it helps.