# Using XUL and JSON, JSON.Parse function do not work

Tags: json, xul

I would like to use XUL and JSON like that:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<button value="click" oncommand="jsonTest()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
// put some js code here

function jsonTest(){

var funcionarios = 
    {
        "Marconildo":
        {
            "url": "http://www.google.com.br/",
            "idade": 34
        }
};

var funcionario = JSON.parse(funcionarios);

alert(funcionario.Marconildo);


}

]]>
</script>
</window>
```

But it do not work...what is wrong? JSON.parse? Would I import some namespace to use this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use JSON.parse in your example because `funcionarios` already contains JSON object. Just alert 'funcionarios.Marconildo.url'

Here is the JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/BZ2gk/

Comment: When i use JSON.parse? Do you have any example?

Comment: If you have a Json String and you want to convert to JSON object, then you will use JSON.parse. You can go through this post for example.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738070/how-to-count-object-in-javascript/8738080#8738080